# how to send the value of the select with the hidden input

Tags: php, mysql

I'm being stuck while trying to send the value of the selected option by the hidden input, in order to insert the values in the mysql table:

```
<form  action="interface.php" method="post">
VLAN: <select name="vlan" onchange="document.getElementById('vlan_id').value=this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="0">Выберите оборудование</option>
<?php
    $res = mysql_query('select `vlan_id`,`number` from `vlan`'); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        printf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $row['vlan_id'], $row['number']);
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="hidden" id="vlan_id name="vlan_id" value="vlan_id" />
```

interface.php

```
 $val3 = $_POST['vlan'];
 $val4 = $_POST['vlan_id'];

 $result_insert =  mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `ADRESSA`.`interface` ( `vlan`,`vlan_id`) VALUES ('$val3','$val4');") 
            or die ("<b>Query failed:</b> " . mysql_error());
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing a quote on hidden id attr try to change

```
<input type="hidden" id="vlan_id name="vlan_id" value="vlan_id" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" id="vlan_id" name="vlan_id" value="vlan_id" />
```

**Note** :- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Also prevent sql injection by escaping strings like:-

```
$val3 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vlan']);
$val4 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vlan_id']);
```

For get value and id change:-

```
onchange="document.getElementById('vlan_id').value=this.options[this.options.selectedIndex].text;"
```

you will get :- `Array ( [vlan] => 1 [vlan_id] => ss )` also change query according values

Comment: thank you very much, now the value is inserting, but the new problem is that value is submitting in the both columns, so instead of "name" "5" i see "5" "5"

Comment: cause you set value as a id in select option and onchane also vlan_id with same

Comment: and what i need to change in order to upload corresponding values?

Answer (score 0):

missing double quotes

```
<input type="hidden" id="vlan_id" name="vlan_id" value="vlan_id" />
                                ^here
```

**UPDATE :**

```
<form  action="interface.php" method="post">
VLAN: <select name="vlan" >
<option value="0">Выберите оборудование</option>
<?php
    $res = mysql_query('select `vlan_id`,`number` from `vlan`'); 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
        echo '<option value="'.$row['vlan_id'].'@##@'.$row['number'].'">'.$row['number'].'<option>';
    }
?>
</select>
```

**PHP**

```
 $vlan = $_POST['vlan'];

 if($vlan!=0)
 {
     list($val4, $val3) = explode("@##@",$vlan);
      $result_insert =  mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `ADRESSA`.`interface` ( `vlan`,`vlan_id`) VALUES ('$val3','$val4');") 
            or die ("<b>Query failed:</b> " . mysql_error());
 }
```

Comment: i see, but now the problem is that only the value of option is inserted

Comment: what is inserted in the vlan_id of your table

Comment: into vlan_id i'm inserting the corresponding id of the selected number. For example: i'm selecting the number 4330 which id is 3 and my aim is to insert into the table values 4330 into number and 3 into vlan_id

Comment: the goal is to insert the selected value as vlan_id and the selected number as number