# How to $_POST one value of two <option> inside the same <select>?

Tags: php, html

I have a `<select>` but for some reasons I need to `echo` two `<option>` inside. So, the code looks like something like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="select2" id="select2">
       echo "<option value='" . $row['sectionid'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
       echo "<option hidden value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['id'] . "</option>";
</select>
```

The two `<option>` are under the same name which is select2.

```
$var=$_POST['select2'];
```

My question is how to `$_POST` one value of those?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by `how to $_POST one value of those`

Comment: Hope now is clearer. @Pupil

Comment: Hope now is clearer. @NickParsons

Comment: The value of `$_POST['select2']` will always be `$row['sectionid']`, since the user cannot choose the second option (`hidden`). Do you need to know the `$row['id']` that "goes with" the selected `$row['sectionid']`?

Comment: Check this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821794/how-to-send-the-value-of-the-select-with-the-hidden-input

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus I want to change the value of `$_POST['select2']` to be `$row['id']` instead of `$row['sectionid']`.

Answer (score 0):

From the exchange in the comments it *sounds* like you want the user to see `$row['name']` and the `$_POST['select2']` to have the value `$row['id']`.

You would get that result if you construct the `<option>` like so:
`echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['name'] . "</option>";`

That would eliminate the need for the second hidden option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to get $row['sectionid'] as well as $row['id']. For this you don't need to put 2 options and fetch their value independently. You can keep data-id attribute in the same option field to store $row['id'].Then you can combine both values and feed in one common hidden input field.

```
<form id="appform" name="appform"><input id="requireField" name="requireField" value="" type="hidden"><select type="text" id="city" name="city"><option value="31" data-id="2">Faridabad</option><option value="32" data-id="3">Delhi</option></select></form><script>$("#city").change(function(){var combined_value=   $("#city").val()+" and " +$("#city option:selected").attr('data-id');alert("Value is "+$("#city").val()+" data id is "+$("#city option:selected").attr('data-id'));$("#requireField").val(combined_value);});</script>
```